# In Win7 can both User and System "TEMP" variables point to the same directory?

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables, temporary-files

I know i *can* do it, but is it a bad practice? It will look like this:

(System)TEMP -> E:\TEMP
(User)TEMP -> E:\TEMP
(System)TMP -> E:\TEMP
(User)TMP -> E:\TEMP

Comment: Did you want to ask this?  
(System)TMP  -> E:\TEMP  
(System)TEMP -> E:\TEMP  
(User)TMP    -> E:\TEMP  
(User)TEMP   -> E:\TEMP   
(swapped one `TMP` and one `TEMP`)

Comment: @Hennes yes! sorry, I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always: it depends.

If your TEMP folder has an access control list giving almost all access to anyone on new files and folders and if there is a system process that is

1. storing sensitive information in TEMP
2. not locking the files
3. not changing the default access rights
4. not cleaning the files up

then you might end up with a user being able to read this information. Or even worse with a user being able to modify this information. There are known attacks on Unix with processes using temp files and not handling them in a secure way.

So in my opinion it is **not** good practice to use the same TEMP folder for SYSTEM and users. BTW, why would you want to do so? And what about the LocalService and NetworkService accounts, why not change these also?

Comment: The reason is kind of silly, i always keep a RAMDisk active and for saving SSD life i want to prevent any unnecessary write on it (SSD). I tought RAMDisk would be a great place for a temp folder, and the software i use to make it has an option to re-create a folder named TEMP at startup. Just one folder..."Why not merge them?" i asked myself, and here we are :D. I'm the only user on this pc, i'll give it a try, thanks for the answer.

Comment: If you want to do it, go ahead. If you want to make it safer, you can set the access rights so that everyone can create new files and folders under TEMP, but the created objects can only be accessed (read, written, deleted) by the owner.

Answer (score 1):

I would call it great practice, unless there is some confidential info that's to be stored in a user's temp folder (which is likely why every user has their own, and system has a separate one). It all should be deleted in the end, but that's the worst downside I could think of.